# draw a movable canvas on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-canvas

i want to draw a canvas that will be movable on a Jpanel. That is when the user clicks on the canvas and drags it it must move to a new positon. i have implemented the MouseMotionListener but i have no idea of what to include inside to make the canvas move as per requierements. here is the DisplayCanvas class:

```
class DisplayCanvas extends Canvas
{
    public DisplayCanvas()
    {
        setBounds(20, 40, 300, 300);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
class shape extends JFrame  implements MouseMotionListener{

static JPanel panel;
static Container contentpane;
static DisplayCanvas canvas;
shape()
{
    canvas=new DisplayCanvas();
    canvas.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    panel= new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(20,20,250,140);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    contentpane = getContentPane();
    contentpane.add(canvas);
    contentpane.add(panel);
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {}
}
```

this is how i test it.

```
public class display 
{
    static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        frame=new shape();
        frame.setBounds(380, 200, 500, 400);
        frame.setTitle("SHAPE AND COLOR");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

NB: please do not suggest that i use the JPanel am required to use the canvas.

Comment: Then you'll be [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact you don't want to extend `JPanel` seems quite weird but it is not unfeasible. Yet you will likely encounter issues at some point because you are mixing lightweight and heavyweight components. You will probably have visual glitches and other display issues.

However I would draw your attention to several important mistakes you made in your current code:

1. Don't extends classes if not needed (no need to extend `JFrame` nor `Canvas`)
2. Don't make variables `static` unless absolutely necessary
3. Follow Java naming conventions: class names always start with an Upper-case letter
4. Don't use a `null` `LayoutManager`.

Here is a snippet illustrating very basic way you can make this work (code needs to be refactored to separate aspects properly)

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.LayoutManager2;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestHeavyweightLightweight {

    public class MyLayoutManager implements LayoutManager2 {

        private Map<Component, Rectangle> constraints = new LinkedHashMap<Component, Rectangle>();

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
            constraints.put(comp, comp.getBounds());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
            constraints.remove(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            for (Rectangle r : constraints.values()) {
                rect = rect.union(r);
            }
            return rect.getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            for (Map.Entry<Component, Rectangle> e : constraints.entrySet()) {
                e.getKey().setBounds(e.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            if (constraints instanceof Rectangle) {
                this.constraints.put(comp, (Rectangle) constraints);
            } else {
                addLayoutComponent((String) null, comp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {

        }

        public void setConstraints(Component component, Rectangle rect) {
            constraints.put(component, rect);
        }

        public class MouseDragger extends MouseAdapter {
            private Point lastLocation;
            private Component draggedComponent;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                draggedComponent = e.getComponent();
                lastLocation = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedComponent, e.getPoint(), draggedComponent.getParent());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point location = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(draggedComponent, e.getPoint(), draggedComponent.getParent());
                if (draggedComponent.getParent().getBounds().contains(location)) {
                    Point newLocation = draggedComponent.getLocation();
                    newLocation.translate(location.x - lastLocation.x, location.y - lastLocation.y);
                    newLocation.x = Math.max(newLocation.x, 0);
                    newLocation.x = Math.min(newLocation.x, draggedComponent.getParent().getWidth() - draggedComponent.getWidth());
                    newLocation.y = Math.max(newLocation.y, 0);
                    newLocation.y = Math.min(newLocation.y, draggedComponent.getParent().getHeight() - draggedComponent.getHeight());
                    setConstraints(draggedComponent, new Rectangle(newLocation, draggedComponent.getSize()));
                    if (draggedComponent.getParent() instanceof JComponent) {
                        ((JComponent) draggedComponent.getParent()).revalidate();
                    } else {
                        draggedComponent.getParent().invalidate();
                        draggedComponent.getParent().validate();
                    }
                    lastLocation = location;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                lastLocation = null;
                draggedComponent = null;
            }

            public void makeDraggable(Component component) {
                component.addMouseListener(this);
                component.addMouseMotionListener(this);
            }

        }

    }

    private Canvas canvas;
    private JPanel panel;

    protected void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestHeavyweightLightweight.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        MyLayoutManager mgr = new MyLayoutManager();
        panel.setLayout(mgr);
        panel.add(canvas, new Rectangle(20, 40, 300, 300));
        MyLayoutManager.MouseDragger mouseDragger = mgr.new MouseDragger();
        mouseDragger.makeDraggable(canvas);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestHeavyweightLightweight().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank u Polet..this is exactly what i wanted to have a moving canvas and i have read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html it realy helped me